# TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar. No stream

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, image-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(cam,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
cnt = contours[0]

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)

for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
    cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
    cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

cv2.imshow('img',cam)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to find contours when streaming from my drone to detect contours of a gutter but I get this error. I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing read() function that is used to capture frames from the source camera. Let me know if that was the issue.

Comment: what code would I have to add?

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')
if not cam.isOpened():
    print("VideoCapture failed to open")

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()

    if ret == False:
        print("frame empty")
        break

    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255,0)
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
    cnt = contours[0]

    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)

    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
        start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
        end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
        far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
        cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
        cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

   cv2.imshow('img',frame)
   cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I think you can do something like this to solve the problem with your code.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am trying to feed this code to my drone so it would follow the line. Any way I can accomplish that? I am not too sure how to do that

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar with that. Raise another question with valid explanation someone will help you. Accept answer if it solved the issue.

Comment: Actually I received an error with `too many values to unpack`.  contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)

Comment: what does 2 and 1 indicate.?

Comment: `im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` this is valid code for getting contours from the image. Where thresh is calculated as `ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `cam` object as image. `cv2.VideoCapture` objects are used for reading frames.

```
# create cv2.VideoCapture object with your parameters
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')

# check if the object created successfully
if not cam.isOpened():
    print("VideoCapture failed to open")

# start reading frames until user interrupts or end of file is encountered
while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()

    if ret == False:
        print("frame empty")
        break

    # process frame here

    # display frame
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    # if 'q' is pressed, then quit loop
    if k == ord('q')
        break
```